# tensorflow gpu serving without docker on "windows"

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to serve a TensorFlow model with Nvidia GPU support in windows 10 (version 20H2, OS Build 19042.1165). To the best of my understanding, I think the best way to do the serving is using Docker image tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu. But to do this in windows we need to install nvidia-docker2 using WSL2. But my organization doesn't allow us to register in the windows insider program and without it, I am unable to install the CUDA toolkit in WSL2.

So, is there any other way to serve the tf model with "GPU support" other than using docker?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only solution is to build from source, but that is not officially supported for windows.
Here is the [link](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-gpu-serving-without-docker-on-windows/3825) if someone wants to build tf serving from source :